# Displaying Posts from Multiple Categories in Custom Post Type with Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm currently working on a university website, where I've created a Custom Post Type (CPT) to manage all the academic programs offered by the university.

I'm facing an issue when trying to display posts in Elementor. I can easily filter posts by individual categories, such as:

- Undergraduate programs
- Distance learning

However, this approach shows me all posts that belong to either category, whereas I need to display posts that meet both criteria simultaneously.

Creating a massive and complex category tree was considered, but it would be cumbersome and problematic to manage. I'm looking for a way to intersect multiple categories when displaying posts to solve this issue.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this, or are there alternative approaches to effectively manage and display these posts in Elementor?

Thank you very much for your assistance!